# DistinctCount + LastNonEmpty within OVER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I used to have the following code in order to get all '-' actions over all customers:

```
with
T1 as
(
select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer4',
    [Date] = '2017-01-01',
    [Action] = '+'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer6',
    [Date] = '2017-01-02',
    [Action] = '+'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer4',
    [Date] = '2017-01-03',
    [Action] = '-'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer4',
    [Date] = '2017-01-04',
    [Action] = '+'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer4',
    [Date] = '2017-01-05',
    [Action] = '-'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer6',
    [Date] = '2017-01-06',
    [Action] = '-'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer8',
    [Date] = '2017-01-07',
    [Action] = '+'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer8',
    [Date] = '2017-01-08',
    [Action] = '-'

union all 

select
    [Contract] = 'Contract1',
    [Customer] = 'Customer4',
    [Date] = '2017-01-09',
    [Action] = '+'
)

select 
    [Customer],
    [Date]  
from T1
where [Action] = '-'
```

Right now I need to do it over Contract field. It means I have to return Contract and Date values when last action is '-' over all customers with '+' action before that date. The very expected output should be:

```
Date         | Contract
------------ | ------ 
2017-01-06   | Contract1   
2017-01-08   | Contract1
```

The expected algorithm should be something like the following:

```
[PlusDC] = count(distinct iif([Action] = '+',Customer,NULL)) over (partition by [Contract] order by [Date])
[MinusDC] = count(distinct iif([Action] = '-',Customer,NULL)) over (partition by [Contract] order by [Date])
```

But:

- It doesn't work anyway.
- Even if it worked, even if [PlusDC] = [MinusDC], it would return the value 2017-01-09, which is incorrect.

Roughly saying, I have to check the following code against all customers:

1. [Action] = '-' for the current row.
2. lag([Action],1) = '-' (or Null, if the customer records appear later the current day) for every single customer.

**Update**: In order to make things even more clear, I've made a column-orientated view of my data:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date         | Contract  | Customer4  | Customer6 | Customer8 | All |
| ------------ | --------- | ---------  | --------- | --------- | --- |
| 2017-01-01   | Contract1 |     +      |           |           |     |
| 2017-01-02   | Contract1 |            |     +     |           |     |
| 2017-01-03   | Contract1 |            |           |           |     |
| 2017-01-04   | Contract1 |     -      |           |           |     | <-- Customer6 still has a '+'
| 2017-01-05   | Contract1 |     +      |           |           |     | 
| 2017-01-06   | Contract1 |     -      |           |           |     | <-- Customer6 still has a '+'
| 2017-01-07   | Contract1 |            |     -     |           |  -  | <-- All customers has '-' or null as a last action
| 2017-01-08   | Contract1 |            |           |     +     |     |
| 2017-01-09   | Contract1 |            |           |     -     |  -  | <-- All customers has '-' or null as a last action
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The All column represents the actual state of all customers (the rows I need). As you might notice 2017-01-04 and 2017-01-06 weren't real '-' within the Contract field. The Contract1 isn't closed, it still has a Customer6 open. It's easy when you have a certain number of customers per a contract. What about countless?

Any practical suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers I've come up with my own solution which is as correct as Søren's and as fast as shA.t's ones. Thanks guys!

```
,[SelfJoinSet] as (
select 
    T1.[Contract], -- Contract from the base
    T1.[Date], -- Date from the base
    T2.[Customer], -- Customers from the current contract
    T2.[Action], -- ActionType of the customer
    -- RowNumber in order to get the last record for each customer within the current contract:
    [RN] = row_number() over (partition by T2.[Customer],T1.[Date] order by T2.[Date] desc) 
from T1
    left join T1 as T2 -- SelfJoin 
    on T1.[Contract] = T2.[Contract] -- Within the current contract
    and T1.[Date] >= T2.[Date] -- Get all records till the current date    
where T1.[Action] = '-' --Filter out all '+' actions, we'll get only '-' records anyway (for performance optimization reasons).
)

select 
    [Contract],
    [Date]
from [SelfJoinSet]
where [RN] = 1 --Show only last record per each customer
group by [Contract],[Date] -- Collapse all to the base table records
having count(distinct iif([Action] = '-',[Customer],NULL)) = count(distinct [Customer]) -- Leave only records where the last action is  '-' for all customers
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
;with tt as (
    select T1.[Contract], T1.[Date], T1.[Action], t.[Customer], t.[Action] lAction, t.[Date] lDate
        -- this `rn` will give me the last action for each other customer older that each Date
        , row_number() over (partition by T1.[Contract], T1.[Date], t.[Customer] order by t.[Date] desc) rn
    from T1
    -- I use this self left join to gather data with:
    left join T1 t
        on T1.[Contract] = t.[Contract]    -- same Contract
        and T1.[Date] > t.[Date]           -- older than current date
        and T1.[Customer] != t.[Customer]  -- for other customers
    -- So I will have actions of other customer older than each date
)
select [Contract], [Date]
from T1
-- I just check if there is not any data in `tt` with:
where not exists(
    select 1
    from tt 
    where tt.[Contract] = T1.[Contract]   -- same contract
      and tt.[Date] = T1.[Date]           -- same date
      and rn = 1                          -- only last action
      and (T1.[Action] = '+'              -- current customer's action is '+'
      or isnull(lAction, '+') = '+')      -- or others last actions is '+'
    )   
group by [Contract], [Date];
```

Comment: It should check all customers last action (it must be '-'), grouping by Contract. See http://pastebin.com/xZvNJ1D1. I've changed 2017-01-05 action to '+' and you code still returns the same, but it shouldn't, the last action for Customer4 is '+', so, It should return nothing at all.

Comment: You've got me wrong, I've re-described the task visually, see the updated data.

Comment: finally, I got what you want, do check my edited answer -HTH ;).

Comment: I've tested it against my real table. It didn't pass this case: http://pastebin.com/N3Zwd6M7 Thanks anyway! I'll post my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am going to solve this by first filling out a table like you did. What I will do is repeat every combination of customers and contracts for each date.

I append this CTE to your example code:

```
,
FullTable as
(
select
a.[Contract]
,a.[Customer]
,b.[Date]
,c.[Action]
,count(c.[Action]) over (partition by a.[Contract],a.[Customer] order by b.[Date]) c
from
(select distinct  
    [Contract],
    [Customer]
from T1) a
inner join 
(select distinct  
    [Contract],
    [Date]
from T1) b
on a.[Contract]=b.[Contract]
left join t1 c
on c.[Contract]=a.[Contract] and a.[Customer]=c.[Customer] and b.[Date]=c.[Date]
)
```

Now the Fulltable does two things, it makes sure there is a row for each customer for each day. When there is no action for that customer in your source data the Action is NULL. 
The second thing I do is count the number of previous actions using a windowed count

```
count(c.[Action]) over (partition by a.[Contract],a.[Customer] order by b.[Date]) c
```

The count does not count NULL values, so this in effect groups the data, with one group for each customer for each date there is a value, and any rows that come directly after with NULL actions get the same group

Here is the data for customer 4

```
Contract    Customer    Date        c   Action
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-01  1   +
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-02  1   NULL
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-03  2   -
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-04  3   +
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-05  4   -
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-06  4   NULL
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-07  4   NULL
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-08  4   NULL
Contract1   Customer4   2017-01-09  5   +
```

Now I make a new CTE called DaillyStatus. This CTE fills in the NULLS, so that each day now holds the most recent status for that contract and customer in stead of NULL. This means that for each day in the table the status for each customer contract combination can be found. To do this I simply get the MAX for each group I just found

```
,DailyStatus as
(
select
[Contract]
,[Customer]
,[Date]
,[Action]
,c
,max([Action]) over (partition by [Contract],[Customer],c) FilledAction
from
FullTable
)

Contract    Customer    Date        c   FilledAction    Action
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-01  0   NULL    NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-02  1   +       +
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-03  1   +       NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-04  1   +       NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-05  1   +       NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-06  2   -       -
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-07  2   -       NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-08  2   -       NULL
Contract1   Customer6   2017-01-09  2   -       NULL
```

Using this table we can get the status for each customer for each date in the table. Since '+'>'-'> NULL we can find the dates where all customer has a '-' as latest actionor has had no action on or before that date (NULL)

```
select
[Contract]
,[Date]
,max(FilledAction) 
from  DailyStatus
group by [Contract],[Date]
having max(FilledAction) ='-'
```

The full solution is here:

```
,FullTable as
(
select
a.[Contract]
,a.[Customer]
,b.[Date]
,c.[Action]
,count(c.[Action]) over (partition by a.[Contract],a.[Customer] order by b.[Date]) c
from
(select distinct  
    [Contract],
    [Customer]
from T1) a
inner join 
(select distinct  
    [Contract],
    [Date]
from T1) b
on a.[Contract]=b.[Contract]
left join t1 c
on c.[Contract]=a.[Contract] and a.[Customer]=c.[Customer] and b.[Date]=c.[Date]
)
,DailyStatus as
(
select
[Contract]
,[Customer]
,[Date]
,[Action]
,c
,max([Action]) over (partition by [Contract],[Customer],c) FilledAction
from
FullTable
)
select
[Contract]
,[Date]
,max(FilledAction) 
from  DailyStatus
group by [Contract],[Date]
having max(FilledAction) ='-'
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks promising! I'll test it later.

Comment: I've tested against my data and it seems to be heavy. Also it didn't pass this case: http://pastebin.com/Jauig67u However it's an edge case. Thanks. I've got the point! I'll post my solution with edge cases and faster way to deal big datasets.